# gcc -m32 error /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile an application for both `64bit` and `32bit` systems. During compilation I am receving an error for the `32bit` application:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read around and found that I need `gcc-multilib` so I tried to install it:

```
me@ubuntu:~/bin/c/find-files$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-multilib is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-41 linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It's already installed. So I look a little more and found that I should be exporting to the `lib32` directory:

```
me@ubuntu:~/bin/c/find-files$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/lib32:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Tried to compile again, same error. Then I though maybe if I used `g++` and installed it's multilib:

```
me@ubuntu:~/bin/c/find-files$ sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++-multilib is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-41 linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I cross compile an application for both `32bit` and `64bit` operating systems?